# How can I pass a variable to an event handler?

Tags: javascript, image, onclick, carousel

Apologies if my problem sounds trivial to JS experts.
I've created an image slider (carousel) and, while loading thumbnails, I'm trying to create a reference to a full-size image, so that when a thumbnail is clicked - the image opens in another div.

The relevant code within window.onload handler is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numImages; ++i) {
    var image = images[i],
        frame = document.createElement('div');
    frame.className = 'pictureFrame';
    /* some styling skipped */
    carousel.insertBefore(frame, image);
    frame.appendChild(image);

  } /* for */
```

My first attempt was to add "onclick" at the end of the for loop:

```
frame.onclick= function ()  { 
        var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
   largeImage.style.display = 'block';
   largeImage.style.width=200+"px";
   largeImage.style.height=200+"px";
   var url=largeImage.getAttribute('src'); 

   document.getElementById('slides').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("slides").innerHTML="<img src='url' />"; 

    }
```

However, this may only work with hard-coded ids (e.g. 'largeImage').
Ideally, I need to pass image.src as a parameter but this `(frame.onclick= function (image.src))` will not work.
My next thought was to put all logic of getting image.src to a separate function and displaying it with `frame.onclick= myFunction;`
However, I came over an example:

```
<input type="button" value="Click me" id="elem">
<script>
  elem.onclick = function(event) {
    // show event type, element and coordinates of the click
    alert(event.type + " at " + event.currentTarget);
    alert("Coordinates: " + event.clientX + ":" + event.clientY);
  };
</script>
```

And here it is above me to understand why in this example a handler can accept a parameter.

What would be a correct way of assigning an image to the onclick event? Or is there a better way of turning a thumbnail into href?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it might not be the best way, you could place the full size image path as a data-attribute on your thumbnail.

```
<img id="thumbnail" src="thumbnailpath" data-fullSizeImage="fullSizePath">
```

Then on your onclick, you could access the thumbnail element and get it's data- attribute.

```
function onClick(event){
    var fullSizePath = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-fullSizeImage");

    //Do whatever you want with fullsizepath
}
```

Code is untested; but, something like that should work based on my experience.

data attributes are a very flexible custom attribute for developers to use. Essentially you start with "data-" and then append a name to represent the attribute. Here is the [documententation link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*).

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be a step forward. Though had to use var url = event.target.attributes.getNamedItem('data-fullSizeImage').value; instead.

Comment: @user2097141 Be careful with `event.target`. It and `event.currentTarget` can have very different results. I find `event.currentTarget` much more reliable and predictable; because, it always refers to the element that the event was attached to. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) from more information.

Comment: I agree and this seems to return correct image paths: var url = event.currentTarget.attributes.getNamedItem('data-fullSizeImage').value; Thanks for your help! Now need to find  out how to display large images in their div using url and div id, but that's a different issue.

Comment: You could either place a image inside the div, or try setting the background image of the div. Placing an image inside the div will probably be easier mainly because of image size. Don't forget to accept an answer to this question. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) (that is, an anonymous function) and register it as an event handler to access variables from outside the event handler inside the event handler itself:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numImages; ++i) {
    /* create element */
    element.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        console.log('The index is ' + i);
    });
}
```

However, **this will not quite work**, since the variable `i` is changed every time the loop increases it, and closures don't "capture" the current value, only the reference itself, so at the end `i` will be equal to `numImages` for each event listener.

If you're using ES6 you can overcome this by [using `let` (or `const`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) to prevent this behavior:

```
for (let i = 0; i < numImages; ++i) {
    /* create element */
    element.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        console.log('The index is ' + i);
    });
}
```

If using ES6 is not an option, you can still accomplish this in ES5 and earlier by wrapping the inside of your loop in a function that takes `i` as a parameter, which makes sure each event handler references different variables, since these parameters are different variables for each iteration:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numImages; ++i) {
    (function (index) {
        /* create element */
        element.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            console.log('The index is ' + index);
        });
     })(i); /* pass in i here, which will be assigned to the index parameter */
}
```